# Lookup not closing after selecting a value

Tags: visualforce, lookup, force.com-sites

I am facing some issues with a lookup.

We developed a Visualforce page on a Salesforce site. On this page, user have multiple fieds to fill, including a lookup. It opens, displays rows but do not close when user selects a value.

We looked at the javascript console, and the following error always occurred :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at doLookupPick (main.js:38)
at lookupPick (main.js:43)
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (LookupResultsFrame:17)
```

Any idea ?
For information, we didn't overwrite the lookup system, but are using the normal way to display a lookup :

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Case.Additional_Address_of_the_customer__c}" id="address_of_the_customer"/>
```

It doesn't seem to be a browser error, as it happens on both Chrome and Mozilla

Thanks!

Comment: If you have some custom JavaScript code, it might be conflicting with standard JavaScript functions.

Comment: Same error occured when I removed all the JS code ... But it worked well when I removed all the code except the inputField line. I'll give updates if I can find the issue!